# Visualizing the smooth terms in a logistic regression (GAM model)

Tags: logistic, data-visualization, logit, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

We have a a logistic regression model (i.e. `family=binomial`) estimated with `gam` of the `mgcv` package. How to visualize the smooth terms?

A quick Google search shows (e.g. [this](https://github.com/danilofreire/r-scripts/blob/master/gam.R) or [this](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?type=supplementary&id=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0152643.s006)) that a few guys use `trans=plogis` in the plotting, which I simply don't understand. It suggests that they are trying to convert the results from logit-scale to the original (probability) scale, but why? It makes absolutely no sense without adding the intercept and adding all of the parametric terms (and in that latter case, specifying the level which was used for all of the parametric terms)...

In contrast, using `trans=exp` would be the logical choice for visualization in my understanding: results don't depend on the intercept, don't depend on the parametric terms, and can be conveniently labeled as 'Odds ratio (OR)'.

It seems so straightforward, yet, I wasn't able to find a single example for `trans=exp`, so I started to wonder if I miss something here...

Comment: Without knowing more about what you are doing or seeing the output, I wonder if this is where one of those "bowtie" plots may come into play. Where the values are compared to a select reference value. See Figure 2: https://academic.oup.com/humrep/article/30/8/1942/950876

Comment: @hlsmith Yes, that's exactly what I have in my mind! The question is: what transform they have used... Unfortunately the paper doesn't document it (and the script doesn't seem to be public), but here is my problem, because I think it must be `exp` (not `plogis`!).

Comment: Yes, I have come across these over the years and I had wanted to make one about 5 years ago, but I don't think I resolved the questions you have. You can get GAM and spline models to kick out pred probabilities, but then how do you set it up with 95% CIs. I popped online and found them in the literature but without any real details in the Methods sections: http://www.revespcardiol.org/en/analysis-of-the-association-between/articulo/S1885585717300841/     I will see what I can find, but tag me if you come across a good article on this topic, since I would be interested in what you found. Thx.

Comment: This may be a little dated (e.g., graphics), though see below link. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d098/abab9446ea9051616bf1607bdc272ceb9574.pdf

Comment: In this example they just exp a set of values plugged into the generated model that were scored.   https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-in-Health-Care-Related/How-do-I-plot-the-spline-effect-in-PHREG/td-p/108326

Comment: As indicated in the link "you [can] convert our output to the probability scale by using the trans argument. The trans argument takes a function that transforms the output. So we can pass the plogis() logistic function to this argument, and all values in plots will be transformed from log-odds to probabilities." https://noamross.github.io/gams-in-r-course/chapter4